# toast only in my activity

Tags: android

I've an app that periodically show same toasts also when app goes to background. So when I use other app I see toasts of my app. How allow show toasts only in my activities?

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "level",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at the Croutons library, which addresses exactly the problem with Toasts showing out of their context.

[Here](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/useful-android-libraries-crouton/) you can find an explanation and where to download it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't tell your Toast to be visible only if the activity is visible. You should rather avoid to call the show() function when your app is running in background.